# C++ SetConsoleTextAttribute changing char in a string

Tags: c++, string, winapi

I have a C++ string which contains some characters. How can I change the char colour if I meet certain chars? Below is the sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    HANDLE h;
    h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    string str = "my name is meow.";
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == 'm')
        {
            //change the char 'm' to red color..
        }

        cout<<str[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Am I the only one who is wondering why the answer is already included in the title of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(str[i] == 'm')
  {
     SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, FOREGROUND_RED);
     cout<<str[i]; 
  }
 else
  {
     SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 15);
     cout<<str[i];
  }
```

maybe this is what you wanna do?

Comment: FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY